# Out of memory exception while using image cropping library

Tags: android

I am using a library which is given below for cropping the images from Gallery as well as photos taken using camera:

https://github.com/rachitwatts/CircleImageCropper

It works perfectly when I crop images from Gallery, but causing out of memory exception while cropping pictures taken using camera.

It will be great if you can provide a solution for this issue or suggest an alternative for this library (I have seen few other libraries, but I want a library which allows images to be cropped as a circle, like in the above mentioned library).

Answer (score 1):

```
This code use manifest file in application tag in:-

android:largeHeap="true" to allocate more heap size.


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:largeHeap="true">...
```

Comment: Will it work properly with lower versions such 2.3 etc?